# Which counter names does cleveref recognize by default?

Tags: cleveref

The package `cleveref` includes the type of the reference along with the counter as the output of its `\cref` command. It also knows some counter names, for instance `theorem`, so that it does not need to specified using say `\crefname` (well, for theorem-like environments, it actually recognizes the environment name, but I suppose we can ignore that difference). These are the 'default definitions' referred to in section 8.1.3 of the `cleveref` documentation. What are all the reference types defined by default?

Below is an example, which if compiled, generates this sentence (in particular, the string 'corollaries' has to come from `cleveref`):

> Theorem 1 and corollaries 2 and 3.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{x}
Blah.
\end{theorem}
\begin{corollary}\label{y}
Blah blah.
\end{corollary}
\begin{corollary}\label{z}
Blah blah blah.
\end{corollary}

\Cref{x,y,z}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source (line 3877-3916 in version `2013/12/28 v0.19`), the `\crefname`'s defined by default are:

- equation - eq. - eqs. (equation - equations  if noabbrev)
- (sub)figure - fig. - figs. (figure - figures if noabbrev)
- page - page - pages
- (sub)table - table - tables
- part - part - parts
- chapter - chapter - chapters
- (sub/subsub)section - section - sections
- (sub/subsub/subsubsub)appendix - appendix - appendices
- enum{i-v} - item - items
- footnote - footnote - footnotes
- theorem - theorem - theorems
- lemma - lemma - lemmas
- corollary - corollary - corollaries
- proposition - proposition - propositions
- definition - definition - definitions
- result - result - results
- example - example - examples
- remark - remark - remarks
- note - note - notes
- algorithm - algorithm - algorithms
- listing - listing - listings
- line - line - lines

There's an analogous set of `\Crefname`'s.